# Is there a way to deploy pure bytecode with hardhat?

Tags: remix, evm, hardhat

Is there a way to deploy pure bytecode with hardhat or remix?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

Given that you have the bytecode and the ABI, you can create a script like this at `scripts/deploy.js`:

```js
const hre = require("hardhat");
const fs = require("fs")
const path = require("path")

async function main() {
  
  var abi = require('/path/to/your/abi.json');
  var bytecode = require('/path/to/your/bytecode.json');

  const Contract = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory(abi, bytecode);
  const deployed = await Contract.deploy("test string");

  await deployed.deployed();

  console.log(
    ` done. Contract deployed to ${deployed.address}!`
  );
}

main().catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
  process.exitCode = 1;
});
```

Where your `abi.json` contains the ABI (standard JSON format). The `bytecode.json` is in the following form from using `solc` (under say another script `./compile.sh`):

```js
const output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));
const bytecode = output.contracts['Contract.sol'].Contract.evm.bytecode.object;
```

Where `input` is obtained from something like (where `yourCodeFile.sol` is the name of your Solidity file, the one you are compiling):

```js
const thePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../', 'contracts', 'yourCodeFile.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(thePath, 'utf-8');

var input = {
    language: 'Solidity',
    sources: {
        'yourCodeFile.sol' : {
            content: source
        }
    },
    settings: {
        outputSelection: {
            '*': {
                '*': [ "*" ]
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Then you export that to the JSON file.
And replace `Contract` with your relevant name of course.

I used the above, e.g., to deploy pure Yul code via Hardhat.

Also note that, with this method, you can put *whatever* bytecode you want in the `/path/to/your/bytecode.json` file and pass to Hardhat!

Comment: No way to do so without the abi? Thanks

Comment: Yes you can, the ABI is just a convenience. You don't have to follow it. But if you use the ABI like above via `hre.ethers...` then when calling the contract `deployed`, `ethers` will check that any function you call is in the ABI and throw an error if not. But if you just call the contract outside of `ethers` (which you can do without the ABI) then you don't need it. So in short: Just put a random ABI there.

Answer (score 1):

These two resources discuss how to deploy bytecode using Remix (might be dated):

https://medium.com/sofocle-technologies/deploying-contract-using-bytecode-myetherwallet-and-remix-10f643a82d40

https://github.com/Sekin/ethereum-bytecode-deployment

Comment: I saw both resources, the second one should work fine, but I would like to know if it's possible to do so through hardhat. If there is some native function that introduces this functionality. Thanks tho!

Answer (score 1):

Using ethers you can deploy a contract just from its bytecode using `sendTransaction`:

```js
const [wallet] = await ethers.getSigners()
const txReceipt = await wallet.sendTransaction({ data: bytecode })
await txReceipt.wait()
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution did not work for me--at least on Polygon Mumbai.  The tx succeeds but no contract or bytecode is displayed, and there's an error stating that the contract doesn't have an address.